# Decryption algorithm for playing files in Android app

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, rc4-cipher

I have a piece of code for decryption of audio files in Adobe Air/Flex app

```
var rsaX:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("rc4", key,Crypto.getPad("pkcs1pad"));
rsaX.decrypt(orgArray);
```

Please, tell me how to decrypt this algorithm in Java for Android application.
Could you please write example of code.

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. Stream ciphers don't use padding, and PKCS #1 actually concerns RSA.

Comment: But this code really encrypted files... My task is decrypt it on java.   Is it impossible?

Comment: Probably not; you just have to find out what the code does. Most likely it simply ignores the padding parameter. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425951/decryption-error-on-android-4-4